# Custom flatMapLatest with nil wrapping

Tags: ios, swift, generics, rx-swift

I have some test function which observers values and map their to another `Observable`:

```
private func test1() {
    selectedTagsVariable
        .asObservable()
        .flatMapLatest { [weak self] tags -> Observable<PostSet> in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return .empty() }
            return strongSelf.postSetObservable(for: tags)
        }
}
```

It's ok, but I don't want each time check **self** value to nil. Of course, I can replace `weak` to `unowned`, but it's not correct.

So, I have created the custom `flatMapLatest`:

```
extension ObservableType {

func xflatMapLatest<A:AnyObject, O: ObservableType>(weak obj: A, selector: @escaping (A, Self.E) throws -> O) -> Observable<O.E> {
    return flatMapLatest { [weak obj] value -> Observable<O.E> in
        guard let strongObj = obj else {
            return Observable.empty()
        }
        return try selector(strongObj, value) as! Observable<O.E>
    }
}
}
```

and it looks like this:

```
private func test2() {
    selectedTagsVariable
        .asObservable()
        .xflatMapLatest(weak: self) { obj, tags -> Observable<PostSet> in
            return obj.postSetObservable(for: tags)
        }
}
```

**Question**: I don't like the typecast in `xflatMapLatest` function in return type (`as! Observable<O.E>`). Can I somehow remove it? Help to refactor this method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to mirror the `flatMapLatest` operator with a simple modification. Have a look at it's signature:

```
func flatMapLatest<O : ObservableConvertibleType>(_ selector: @escaping (Self.E) throws -> O) -> RxSwift.Observable<O.E>
```

As you can see, the resulting type of the `selector` closure has to conform to the `ObservableConvertibleType`, the definition of which is here:

```
public protocol ObservableConvertibleType {
    associatedtype E
    public func asObservable() -> RxSwift.Observable<Self.E>
}
```

Knowing this it's pretty easy to see what little changes you need to do to make it work:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func flatMapLatestWeak<A: AnyObject, O: ObservableConvertibleType>(weak obj: A, selector: @escaping (A, E) throws -> O) -> Observable<O.E> {
        return flatMapLatest { [weak obj] value -> Observable<O.E> in
            guard let strongObj = obj else {
                return Observable.empty()
            }
            return try selector(strongObj, value).asObservable()
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can shorten this method using `Optional<T>`'s `map`:

```
extension ObservableType {
    func flatMapLatestWeak<A: AnyObject, O: ObservableConvertibleType>(weak obj: A, selector: @escaping (A, E) throws -> O) -> Observable<O.E> {
        return flatMapLatest { [weak obj] value in
            try obj.map{ try selector($0 , value).asObservable() } ?? .empty()
        }
    }
}
```